# using Ng-table, adding custom number range filter to a particular column

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been looking at all over the web to find the solution but I wasn't able to find a solution that fits my specific need.

So I have a table (built using ng-table module) with several columns like below.

```
headerA   headerB     headerC_start     headerC_end
-filter-  -filter-    -filter-           -filter-
AAA        AAAA        10                   10
BBB        BBBB        12                   12
CCC        CCCC        13                   13
DDD        DDDD        14                   14
EEE        EEEE        15                   15
FFF        FFFF        22                   22
```

Each filter right below header works as a 'contain' function filter.
What I mean by 'contain' is, if I put '1' in the header C filter, it will show 10, 12, 13, 14 and 15 (since these numbers contain '1') with corresponding data from header A and B.

For header A and B , 'contain' is fine, but I want header C to have 'range' function instead of 'contain. So my purpose is to input the minimum value at headerC_start and maximum value at headerC_end, and I want the table to filter out all the numbers in between that minimum and maximum with all corresponding information form header A and B. So If I put 10 at headerC_start and 14 at headerC_end, it will only show 10, 12,13 and 14 with all corresponding information from header A and header B.

I've tried several different ways to solve this problem including writing my own custom filter function, but I was unable to apply that custom filter function to header_C since all header A, B and C are bound to ng-table module.

Below are snippets of my codes.

---html

```
<table ng-table="someTable" show-filter="true" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
<tr ng-repeat="item in data">


    <td data-title="'headerA'" sortable="'headerA'" filter="{ 'headerA': 'text' }" >
        {{item.attributeA}}
    </td>

    <td data-title="'headerB'" sortable="'headerB'" filter="{ 'headerB': 'text' }" >
        {{item.attributeB}}
    </td>


    <td data-title="'headerC_start'" sortable = "'headerC_start'" filter = "{'headerC_start':'text'}">
        {{item.attributeC}}
    </td>


    <td data-title ="'headerC_end'" sortable = "'headerC_end'" filter="{'headerC_end':'text'}">
        {{item.attributeC}}
    </td>
```

---JS

```
angular.module('someApp', ['ngTable', 'ui.bootstrap', 'mainApp'])

.config(function someAppConfig($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/some', {
            templateUrl: 'view/some.html',
            controller: 'some_table_controller'
        });
})



.controller('some_table_controller', function ($scope, $http, $filter, NgTableParams) {


    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/some/range/xxxx", {cache: true})
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.something = response.data;


            $scope.somethingTable = new NgTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 10

            },

                {


                getData: function (params) {
                    if (params.sorting()) {
                        $scope.data = $filter('orderBy')($scope.something, params.orderBy());
                    } else {
                        $scope.data = $scope.something;
                    }
                    if (params.filter()) {
                        $scope.data = $filter('filter')($scope.data, params.filter());
                    } else {
                        $scope.data = $scope.data;
                    }
                    $scope.data = $scope.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                    return $scope.data;
            }

        });

    });
});
```

For several hours, I've tried the most right one on this example, (custom filter function)

http://codepen.io/christianacca/pen/yNWeOP

But I couldn't find a way to implement the example code to my script.

I would really appreciate any input!!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have just solved a similar issue. I used custom filter

HTML (using Thymeleaf)

```
<td th:attr="data-title=|'My Header'|" filter="{'headerA' : 'numberRange'}">
```

Filter:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="ng-table/filters/numberRange.html">
    <form class="form-inline">
        <span>Between</span>
        <input type='number' ng-model="params.filter()[name + 'Min']" name="filter-numberRange" class="form-control" min="1" />
        <span>and</span>
        <input type='number' ng-model="params.filter()[name + 'Max']" name="filter-numberRange" class="form-control" min="1" />
     </form>
</script>
```

On your javascript

```
var minRange = params.filter().headerAMin;
var maxRange = params.filter().headerAMax;
```

Hope it helps